# This android code causes my app to crash

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android development using Java, and I came to how to save application data in SharedPreferences class ..

When trying to make this attempt, the app crashs ..

This android java code causes the app to crash when trying to save the data

```
package com.example.savedata;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences sp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView tv;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp = getSharedPreferences ("MYFILENAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    tv.setText(sp.getString("Data","0"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void saveDate(View v){
    sp = getSharedPreferences("MYFILENAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    TextView tv;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    ed.putString("Data", (String) tv.getText());
    ed.commit();
}

}
```

Can anybody help me telling why does this code crash ?

Comment: Can you provide the output from logcat at the time of the crash so we can see the stack trace, etc?

Comment: Could you also provide your layout?

Comment: show your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Also, I am very curious where you are calling `saveData()` from. It looks like it may be an `onClick` for a `Button` except I don't see a `Button`

Comment: the line:  ed.putString("Data", (String) tv.getText()); is the problem causer because this cast is not accepted, however, tv.getText().toString() will work fine .. thanks everyone :)

Comment: You need to post the logcat output as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

instead of this:

```
ed.putString("Data", (String) tv.getText());
```

you can use:

```
ed.putString("Data", tv.getText().toString());
```